# Google Sheet Web-scraping ImportXml Xpath on Yahoo Finance

Tags: regex, xpath, import, google-sheets-formula, yahoo-finance

I am trying to get stock information from Yahoo Finance with webscraping ImportXml Xpath,into my Google Sheet. I can get it to work with the %change, but not with the price, there I get a number I dont reconize anywhere on the page, can anybody pleas help me.
My xmlImport for my Price look like this:

```
=INDEKS(IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CVNA?p=CVNA";"//*[@id='quote-header-info']/div[3]/div[1]/div/span[1]");1)
```

And my xmlImport for my %Change look like this

```
=INDEKS(IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CVNA?p=CVNA";"//*[@id='quote-header-info']/div[3]/div[1]/div/span[2]");1)
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I can get it to work with the %change, but not with the price, there I get a number I dont reconize anywhere on the page`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the sample output you expect?

Comment: I just added a screenshot to the question. I expect to get a number around 280, depending on the rate, but get the number 11.84791667

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that the discussion has already been advanced. In this case, I would like to respect the discussion. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(IMPORTXML(
 "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CVNA?p=CVNA";
 "//*[@id='quote-header-info']");;3); "\d+.\d+|\d+")+0
```

[image]

[image]

---

### update:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(IMPORTXML(
 "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CVNA?p=CVNA"; 
 "//*[@id='quote-header-info']");;3); "\d+.\d+|\d+"); "."; ",")*1
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a little funny, when I use your formula I still get a number I can not recognize, although I can see it works in your spreadsheet, the number I get is 11.84791667. Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?
I have added a screenshot of the spreadsheet with your formula and the result up in the question

Comment: @jhjorsal check: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QenJ8.png

Comment: @jhjorsal can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I am not quite sure how this work, but here is my try https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O-Sx9Y_OMMPiwzlOWVIO6D87T4LXZ14sMEXak8p7ojA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: And I have all ready tryed to format the cell as number

Comment: @jhjorsal see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NhBxkFAPAeo2I7Z50LVNJ4z72ZodiURoDRIN713NdMA/edit#gid=0 answer updated...

Comment: Thank you very much, now it seems to work, it looks like I was missing the last "d+" in the formula, I got the "+0" with, and it was copy / paste from your code block, so how could I forget I do not know, but thank you

Comment: Hello again
I did not notice it, but it does not look like I get decimals with. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that we in Denmark use comma to separate numbers and decimals (and dot as a 1000 number separator). I can see on your screen dump that you have decimals, but when I check your shared spreadsheet I also do not have decimals, but do you maybe have a solution for this problem.

Comment: use: `=SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CVNA?p=CVNA"; "//*[@id='quote-header-info']");;3); "\d+.\d+|\d+"); "."; ",")*1`

Comment: Thangs a lot, it helped me a lot, but I also have to change the comma to dot (1000 number separator), otherwise the shares with a value above 999 will set too low. I have tried to insert an AND function in SUBSTITUTE, but I can not just make it work, and if I make a SUBSTITUTE around the first SUBSTITUTE, it will also change the commas I have just changed, any suggestions?

Comment: I guess it could be done with regex. can you share such example in your or mine sheet so I could look at it what formula you using and where is the issue (?)

Comment: see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NhBxkFAPAeo2I7Z50LVNJ4z72ZodiURoDRIN713NdMA/edit#gid=0

Comment: Hi again and many thanks :-)
Out of curiosity and to learn, I just need to have figured out exactly what REGEXEXTRACT does, But do you know why I could not just web scrape with IMPORTXML, via a URL and XPATH as I wanted in the beginning. If I go to "Investigate and show source" for the website, it is the right share price that is there, but I was presented with something completely different, in the example with ticker code CVNA, the share price is 288.15 but showed 12.01041667, where did that number come from?

Comment: the latest regex extracts the group `[]+` of digits `0-9` with comma and dot `\.,` and the issue is in locale settings of your spreadsheet because you are using non-US syntax (semicolons ; instead of commas , ) and due to this its a bit trickier because by default google sheets try to auto-convert it and there you get the 12.01 due to conversion to numeral number (tho if you would be importing it as text string you would get the correct value but then you couldn't do any math with it)

Comment: Hello again
Thanks for the reply, and sorry for my late reply, I have been at work (Sailing). Now I almost control the REGEX functions, but one thing that wonder me is the 3 arguments in the INDEX function that you have set to "3", I have searched and searched but can find a description of what it does, and what I can find of explanation - says it should be between 0 and 1,It works but I'm just curious

Comment: index can take 3 arguments where 2nd and 3rd can be skipped. `INDEX(data, number of row to output, number of column to output)` in our case we skipped 2nd argument hence those double commas `,,` and we restricting the output on just 3rd column (`3`)